# Can I modify header in a message that is already exist?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am wondering cause I have a splitter, and I am trying to modify the message header of the file name to suite the need of the program.

I have a file name ABC.tec

since I split into several file and return it to the message channel, therefore I need it to be in different file name

as such

ABC_1.tec

ABC_2.tec

ABC_3.tec

I have tried to change it by

```
StringBuilder stringFileName = new StringBuilder(message.getPayload().getName());

stringFileName = stringFileName.insert(stringFileName.indexOf("."), i++);

MessageBuilder.withPayload(content).copyHeaders()).setHeader("FILE_NAME", stringFileName.toString()).build();
```

However it doesn't work when I print out the values are still the same..

Is there any guide that I can follow?

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of the messagebuiler `build()` method to something.

```
message = MessageBuilder....build();
```